# Does the PFD/ND XFR work when the PFD is on the ND screen on the Airbus A320?

Tags: airbus-a320

So I know the PFD has priority over the ND and that's why if the PFD screen fails its automatically switched to the ND screen. If the ND screens fails it does not get automatically transferred to the PFD screen because the PFD has priority. You can view the ND screen on the PFD screen by pressing the PFD/ND XFR button. So my question is if the PFD is on the ND screen because the PFD screen failed if you press the PFD/ND XFR will it show the ND information on the ND screen, and when you press it again it will go back to the PFD?

Answer (score 4):

From the FCOM A320:
[image: FCOM PFD/ND RECONF]

[image: FCOM PFD/ND RECONF]

As you can see if you fail the PFDU and the PFD is transferred on the NDU, by pressing XFR PFD/ND you will have the ND appearing on the NDU

Full description:

[image]